# How to send files to telegram bot kotlin?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, bots, telegram-bot

I have a spring-boot kotling gradle project. I added this dependency to work with telegram-api:

```
implementation("org.telegram:telegrambots-spring-boot-starter:6.3.0")
```

I implemented my **LongPolling** bot. Sending plain text is pretty easy with **SendMessage**. But now I want to send *files*. In my attached library there is an entity **SendDocument**. But I have absolutely no idea how to work with it. And when I call and fill **SendDocumentBuilder()** I get the following message:

> "Cannot access '': it is package-private in
> 'SendDocumentBuilder'".

Can you please tell me how to send a file without webHook bot implementation and **without direct rest call of telegram-api end-points**?
Is it possible to limit the api of the library I plugged in? *How to initialize SendDocument* entity to call execute() method later?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, I would advise you to actually choose libraries written in it, they will provide a more elegant api.

I'm also recently switched to Kotlin and found a couple of interesting libraries, so far I've settled on some new [library](https://github.com/vendelieu/telegram-bot), I found the syntax more convenient.